# Reading from a csv file, and removing any rows that only have ""

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, streamreader

Reading from a csv file using stream reader and then splitting each value from the row that's being read by a comma.

I would like to remove any row that has empty values within the whole row.

```
{"test", "test", "test", "test"}
{"test1", "test1", "test1", "test1"}
{"", "", "", ""}
```

I would like my method to not process that third row if its empty.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                reader.ReadLine();

                while (reader.Peek() != -1)
                {

                    var line = reader.ReadLine();

                    string[] data = line.Split(',');

                    // Convert data into an object
                    ...
                }
            }
```

I would only like to convert the data into an object if it doesn't look like the 3rd array. **{"", "", "", ""}**

Comment: So, if your line has exactly four columns it should look like _,,,_ What's stops you to check for that before starting to process the line?

Comment: Unrelated: As always when dealing with CSV, I'd recommend to using a CSV library.

Comment: _"It would be nice to be able to check right once the line has been read to see if it's ,,,"_ - what keeps you from doing exactly that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq

```cs
// At least 1 empty value
bool hasEmpty = data.Any(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);

// All values are empty
bool allEmpty = data.All(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);
```

Comment: @Steve corrected to use the array instead

Answer (score 1):

Just add a simple if statement:

```cs
if (data.Any() && !data.All(a => a == string.Empty))
{
   // Convert data into an object
}
```